# How to search by parent and base tag in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, join, junction-table

I have Products and Company tables that look something like this:

```
Company:
id | name
----------
1  | Google

Products
id | companyId | name
---------------------
1  | 1         | Google Home
2  | 1         | Pixel

Tags
id | name
----------
1  | Consumer Electronics
2  | Computer
3  | Cell Phone
```

Now I am not sure if I should do a junction table between company -> tags and products -> tags or if there is a way to have one for both or what. When I am searching for companies I want to be able to use the tags for the company and all children products, ie if I search for a Computer and Cell Phone it should find Google. Then if I am searching for Products by Consumer Electronics and Computer, it should return Google Home.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.